# How to cast varchar with multiple values to int

Tags: arrays, sql-server, casting, integer, varchar

There is a SQL template, which has a `ids` variable:

```
select file_name 
from hist_payout 
where hist_payout_id in (:ids)
```

`ids` is a varchar, looks like `'3, 17, 2001'`, and the error I get is

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Is it possible to cast varchar to int array in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a recent enough version of SQL Server, you could use `STRING_SPLIT` to break this `@varchar` value apart.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20) = '3, 17, 2001';

SELECT
    CAST(TRIM(value) AS INT)
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT(@input, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database and how you are querying it, there are probably better ways to pass a list of values into a query.

But given a query of the form you specify and assuming standard SQL syntax, you can use `LIKE`:

```
where ', ' || :ids || ', ' like '%, ' || cast(hist_payout_id as varchar(255)) || ', %'
```

I do want to emphasize that there are probably better methods, depending on your environment.